# Undefined object property handling in xml parsing

Tags: javascript, php, xml, json, codeigniter

XML object parsing is successful with the defined properties but not for undefined. Say suppose we don't have property and try to assign that to a variable, throws an error as given below :

[image]

The code is written below like this :

$data['id'] =  $xml[0]->response->list->region[0]->id;

But if there is no id attribute exists, then the above error is encountered

Tried by the following conditions :

1. if($xml[0]->response->list->region[0]->id)
2. if($xml[0]->response->list->region[0]->id==false)
3. if($xml[0]->response->list->region[0]->id=="undefined")
4. if (!is_object($xml[0]->response->list->region[0]->id))

All the above was unsuccessful

Parsing code is :

```
$url           =  'xmloutputtingurl';
$xmlContents   =   $this->curl->simple_get($url);   
$xml       =   implexml_load_string($xmlContents);
$data['xml']   =   xml;
```

The receiving xml data is :

[image]

And its output of xml as array is :

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)[19]
  public 'request' => 
    object(SimpleXMLElement)[20]
      public 'state' => string 'California' (length=10)
      public 'city' => string 'Los Angeles' (length=11)
      public 'childtype' => string 'neighborhood' (length=12)
  public 'message' => 
    object(SimpleXMLElement)[21]
      public 'text' => string 'Request successfully processed' (length=30)
      public 'code' => string '0' (length=1)
  public 'response' => 
    object(SimpleXMLElement)[22]
      public 'region' => 
        object(SimpleXMLElement)[23]
          public 'id' => string '12447' (length=5)
          public 'latitude' => string '34.020921' (length=9)
          public 'longitude' => string '-118.411732' (length=11)
      public 'subregiontype' => string 'neighborhood' (length=12)
      public 'list' => 
        object(SimpleXMLElement)[24]
          public 'count' => string '96' (length=2)
          public 'region' => 
            array (size=95)
```

Error is causing if the id is not mentioned under list->region tag in some situations

Can anybody help with this please and also how can the same scenario be achieved from JavaScript as well when parsing json.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What is `$xml[0]`? Show us the parsing code that produces the `$xml`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PHP you can avoid it by using DOM and Xpath and not SimpleXml. This is a different concept, you're using expressions to fetch parts.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXml('<foo attr="bar"/>');
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

var_dump(
  //the attribute value of foo/@attr
  $xpath->evaluate('string(/foo/@attr)'),
  //asking for the value of an non existing attribute returns an empty string
  $xpath->evaluate('string(/foo/@nonexisting)')
);
var_dump(
  //asking for an element will return a node list
  $xpath->evaluate('/foo')->length,
  // if no element is found an empty list is returned
  $xpath->evaluate('/bar')->length
);
```

Output:

```
string(3) "bar"
string(0) ""
int(1)
int(0)
```

The Xpath expressions can contain conditions, let's get region elements without an id child:

`/*/response/list/region[not(id)]`

or with an empty id

`/*/response/list/region[not(string(id) = "")]`

The second argument of DOMXpath::evaluate() is the current context node. So you can fetch a list of nodes, iterate them and use expression relative to them.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXml('<foo attr="bar"><bar/></foo>');
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//*') as $node) {
  var_dump(
    $node->nodeName,
    // count first parent node - 0 or 1
    $xpath->evaluate('count(ancestor::*[1])', $node),
    // count parent nodes without the attribute
    $xpath->evaluate('count(ancestor::*[not(@attr)])', $node)
  );
}
```

In JavaScript most people already do it without realizing it. Have you ever used CSS selectors with jQuery? You are not limited to the browser DOM, the same is possible for loaded or generated XML. CSS selectors are not as powerful as Xpath expression, but this is offset by the APIs in JS.